# Echo causes error before creating image in php?

Tags: php, gd

I have some image creation code that is like this:

```
<?php
//echo "asdf";
create_image(3);
exit();
function create_image($n){
...yada yada
}
?>
```

The code works fine and creates the image without any issue.

But then if I uncomment the "echo asdf" line, I get this error:

```
<?php
echo "asdf";
create_image(3);
exit();
function create_image($n){
...yada yada
}
?>
```

> The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I don't understand why echoing a string on this page breaks the image?  It isn't even within the image function..

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Comment: its because your script is creating the actual image, and adding info to the front of the file makes it not a valid image.

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve here?

Comment: I want a page that displays some text, and then the generated image underneath.

Comment: You cannot mix text and binary responses.

Comment: you will have to put the image creation in its own script then call it like `<img src="scrip.php">`

Comment: Thanks Dagon makes sense, set as answer and I will accept.

Comment: can't answer is was (rightly) closed as a dupe